# Spawning 2d objects randomly, but not overlapping with other objects

Tags: c#, unity3d-2dtools

I'm working on a small game project for school in UNITY, specifically a clone of a snake game called Rattler Race. I'm pretty much a complete beginner with the engine, hence why I'm struggling a bit. The game we're suppose to make has to have 30 unique levels that have ascending complexity, something like this: [Final level](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWu3a.png)

My main problem at the moment is spawning food for the snake so it doesn't overlap with any inner walls or the borders.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpawnFood : MonoBehaviour
{
public GameObject FoodPrefab;

public Transform BorderTop;
public Transform BorderBottom;
public Transform BorderLeft;
public Transform BorderRight;
public Transform Obstacle;

Vector2 pos;

// Use this for initialization
void Start ()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Spawn();
    }
}

void Spawn()
{
    pos.x = Random.Range(BorderLeft.position.x + 5,BorderRight.position.x - 5);

    pos.y = Random.Range(BorderBottom.position.y + 5, BorderTop.position.y - 5);

    Instantiate(FoodPrefab, pos, Quaternion.identity);

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update ()
{

}


}
```

The code is very simple ofcourse because at the moment the game field is empty with no obstacles:
[Current state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COEKb.png)

However my problem is if I was to scale up that tiny red obstacle, like so:
[Big Obstacle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhjbR.png)

The food would spawn behind it(every level has 10 food objects) and be impossible to get. My idea was to build levels off of one object(the "Obstacle") and its copies, I don't really know if that idea is sound yet but I wanted to try.

If theres any way or any method to spawn food objects in locations so they don't overlap with the obstacle, like to check if the space is already occupied or a method that checks if a would be food object intersects with an existing obstacle, I would be very grateful if someone teaches me, because I'm really lost at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your food is exactly one unit long, you could have a coroutine which would check if there is something around that food gameObject, if there isn't anything, you can spawn it.

```
public LayerMask layerMask; //Additional variable so you can control which layer you don't want to be detected in raycast

void Spawn(){
    StartCoroutine(GameObjectExists());
}


IEnumerator GameObjectExists(){

   do{
       yield return null;
       pos.x = Random.Range(BorderLeft.position.x + 5,BorderRight.position.x - 5);
       pos.y = Random.Range(BorderBottom.position.y + 5, BorderTop.position.y - 5);

   }while(Physics2D.OverlapCircle(new Vector2(pos), 1f, layerMask); //1f is the radius of your food gameObject.

  Instantiate(FoodPrefab, pos, Quaternion.identity);
  yield return null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, also what should I select in the Layer Mask dropdown that is on the Inspector? At the moment I selected Everything since I don't know what is the right choice.

Comment: You can learn more about layers here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HR-Tf_6uzwc
For example the only thing I wouldn't like to be checked if it overlaps the circle, is the background, since it doesn't have any influence on the game.